# Lenovo C940: disable temperature shutdown

Tags: lenovo, overheating, temperature

The temperature on my Ubuntu system on a Lenovo Yoga C940 seems to spike over 100 degrees when opening multiple applications. The idle cpu temperature is about 50 degrees. This causes Ubuntu to shut down with the "critical temperature exceeded" warning.

The spike is brief and I monitor the temperature through the applet, so shutting down is very counter-productive. I would like for it to not do that.

There is no temperature level control in the BIOS. I have added

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash thermal.nocrt=1"
```

but that doesn't seem to help.

I have also found a Lenovo tutorial for a different model, [High ambient temperature causing system shutdown - Lenovo Servers](https://support.lenovo.com/se/en/solutions/ht501018), so I suspect I might need to do something with pef-config to control some internal BIOS configuration.

```
$ sudo pef-config --listsections
Unable to get Number of Alert Destinations
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is tracked in ubuntu bug tracker [Lenovo Yoga C940 frequently does thermal shutdown](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1873083) .

The thread contains several workarounds. For me generating thermald configs has helped.

```
sudo apt install acpica-tools
git clone https://github.com/intel/dptfxtract.git
cd dptfxtract
sudo acpidump > acpi.out
acpixtract -a acpi.out
sudo ./dptfxtract *.dat
```

If that doesn't help, to completely disable thermal shutdowns it is possible to disable thermald shutdowns
`echo "disabled" | sudo tee /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/mode`
for the thermal zones that are mentioned in shutdown messages.